# Is there a way to highlight image differences via a color manipulation of 2 images?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working to compare the differences in two image revisions. The image will always be black and white. Currently I have a solution where the image differences are show with red and cyan lines after using openCV to perform an image addition after removing a color channel from each images. What I want to do to reduce visual color, is have one image untouched visually, and the other image to be overlaid. With this overlay, difference in the lines will be highlighted as red, while the other remains black. (Shown in the image). A is the original document revision. B is the one with changes. C is what I would like to display to highlight the changes, and D is what I can currently achieve.
[image: Idea of the revision display]

I had an idea where I could somehow use a subtraction of the images and that that resulting image and somehow add it to the main image. I am very new to computer vision, so I am not sure of all the proper terms. I was thinking of having that subtraction image serve as a mask for the revised image, turn all the black pixels red, and then add that to the "original".

Here is the snippet of code that will generate an output similar to that in block D of the image.

```
np_image_A = np.array(image_A)
np_image_B = np.array(image_B)

# Set the green and red channels respectively to 0. Leaves a blue image
np_image_A[:, :, 1] = 0
np_image_A[:, :, 2] = 0
# Set the blue channels to 0.
np_image_B[:, :, 0] = 0
# Add the np images after color modification
overlay_image = cv2.add(np_image_A, np_image_B)
```

My idea was taking the shape of the below, but was not sure how to progress past here:

```
sub = cv2.subtract(image_b, image_a) # Get the areas of difference in the revised image
alpha = 0.75
revision_img = cv2.addWeighted(sub, alpha, image_a, 1-alpha, 0)
```

After taking the subtraction step, I am left with a black and white image. And upon added to the base image to see the revisions, I am left with a image that is dark. I think that after the subtraction step, something needs to be done to make the black transparent and the white lines turn red, but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to approach this.
First the images are loaded as grayscale. These are inverted, so the background is black (value 0) the the lines are white (value 255). Now you can subtract A from B to get the lines/symbols that were added in B (relative to A). You can use the resulting mask to modify a color version of A to display what B has added.

Result:

[image]

Note the overlay, this is because I used the image you provided. Given the result you have at D, this may not be an issue for you?

Code:

```
    import cv2 
    # load image A as color image
    img = cv2.imread('1a.png')
    # load A and B as grayscale
    imgA = cv2.imread('1a.png',0)
    imgB = cv2.imread('1b.png',0)
    # invert grayscale images for subtraction
    imgA_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(imgA)
    imgB_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(imgB)
    # subtract the original (A) for the new version (B)
    diff = cv2.subtract(imgB_inv, imgA_inv)
    # split color image A into blue,green,red color channels
    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
    # merge channels back into image, subtracting the diff from
    # the blue and green channels, leaving the shape of diff red
    res = cv2.merge((b-diff,g-diff,r))
    # display result
    cv2.imshow('Result',res)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was going for. I never would have thought about the inversion step. You have saved me a few extra days of testing methods. Cheers!